# Why is Google requesting a certificate?

Tags: safari, certificate

I am having an issue on Safari (Have not specifically tested other browsers but never had the problem on accessing same site). When I visit some of my classes on Google Classroom (classroom.google.com) the domain `photos-image-qa.corp.google.com` seems to request/require a client certificate.  The only certificate I can give is an Apple ID certificate.  I have cancelled the dialog multiple times without consequence and have never given the certificate. After clicking `Cancel` the dialog disappears and does not come back for a couple of days even if I reload the page.  I am  unsure how to prevent this message from coming up.  Many others use these classroom site and have never seen a client certificate request on Chrome (macOS), Safari (macOS), Opera (macOS), or Chrome (Chromebook).

**Specs:**

macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Safari 11.1

**My Question(s)**:

Why is Google Classroom requesting a certificate?

How to prevent Google Classroom from requesting a certificate?

What certificate would Google Classroom accept/is Google Classroom looking for?

**Pictures**
**Note:** The black boxes cover up possible sensitive and/or irrelevant information. In private browsing to force the dialog box to come up.
[image]

**Update**: This has also occurred on Google Drive. When I click cancel some of the image previews of the documents go to question marks almost as if the server won't provide the images to Safari without the certificate.

Comment: hmm. What happens if you press the "continue" button? (Can you post an image)

Comment: Never done it and don’t really want to submit my Apple ID certificate to Google.

Comment: sorry, I don't know. Good luck though.